# Very serious login - Worried

Tags: facebook, authentication

my name is Shamcaoblakslbl, I am here about a very serious problem I am very worried about.

So I usually keep my facebook logged in 24/7 and open on my machine. Never been logged out before. So I get back to facebook and it say's "You've been logged out" Oh no!

So I login, it brings me to the usual checkpoint for devices.. okay.
Now I continue and all I see is a 500 internal server error.
I've done EVERYTHING to try to fix this, I've logged in on other machines with no success, browsers, cleared cache. Then I logged into a buddies of mine facebook with no problem.

I'm absolutely loosing my mind right now. Why is my face book the only one that returns a 500 error.

Am I secretly banned? what is it? I'm going nuts. 
While on my friends account I had him to go my profile, it loaded looked like my usual profile. Wasn't down or anything.

I've reset my password, everything I can do successfully. But not make it ANYWHERE passed the device checkpoint.

Is that it for my Facebook?
I've done a TON of searches about this and seen very sad disturbing results that users are forced to make a new Facebook and there is no reason or known cause to this. People are saying it just happens and that's it time for a new Facebook.

I'm worried I lost my memory's messages, friends, contacts, post.

Is this a big joke from Facebook? a really LONG temperry problem? or am I just screwed?

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Comment: @lgy Lmao, do you know how many people are on Facebook? I've been trying to contact support for months, it's not possible.

Comment: @lgy And also, http://i.imgur.com/UHwIF.png this is facebook.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Which is a section of a technical Q&A site regarding programming, specifically a section for people making applications which interact with Facebook's API, it's not for users using facebook.com, try http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ instead maybe

Comment: Thank you man, instead of -repping my question you help guide me to the correct place. Maybe others will learn to be less ignorant from you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Facebook has a new very serious exploit. Content posted on a page can cause the entire account to be ruined for good.

I've had some friends post on my page and it's doing very weird things. Such as a XSS type related attack.

To long to explain but my profile is glitched to the T.

Comment: Holy crap, what is up with the reputation abuse? you -1 my problem that could warn many others including the Facebook dev team about this issue. 

Little corrupt if you ask me.